# Routing error for /users/Sign_out ; Devise signout doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm following this tutorial to build a **dropbox** like application
[Build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940)

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and still learning. According to the tutorial I used devise for authentication, But it has a problem that it doesn't let me sign out once signed in. I'm unable to figure out the solution for this.

I googled and tried to add this in routes.rb

**routes.rb**

```
Dropbox::Application.routes.draw do
 #me devise_for :users
 devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
 root :to => "home#index"
end
```

I am unable to fix this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In routing you have define 'GET'  it should be 'DELETE'

Please change your routes to `devise_for :users`

I think the route for signing out is a DELETE method. This means that your sign out link needs to look like this `<%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>.` Yours doesn't include the :method => :delete part.

please also check your devise initializer file. 
it should be define

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

It will work

Example [rails-devise](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise) , Please clone this.

Comment: I changed it to DELETE from GET ; still the same error . I checked the initializer file and it is :delete.  Any more tips ?

Comment: Thankyou so much. But i have a problem here. I have never used devise and not sure where to add the signout link. the structure is views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb . Should i add this there ? sorry if this is a simple question. Am a novice user.

Comment: @SwethaKogatam - I have added sample rails-devise example.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
devise_for :users
```

From your error

```
Routing error for /users/Sign_out
```

I see that you are using incorrect route, it should be

```
/users/sign_out
```

not

```
/users/Sign_out
```